# Compare json item values simultaneously

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My college has written a function as follows:

```
const wrapper = item => {
    switch (item.type && item.name) {
        case 'Url' && 'Website':
            return Text(values.Website)
        case 'Email' && 'Email':
            return Text(values.Email)
        case 'Mobile' && 'TelegramPhoneNumber':
            return Mobile(values.TelegramPhoneNumber)
        case 'Phone' && 'Phone1':
            return Phone(values.Phone1)
        case 'Phone' && 'Phone2':
            return Phone(values.Phone2)
        default:
            return Text(values[4])
    }
}
```

apparently it gets a json as argument and tries to determine type and name simoltaneously.(This is my understanding of this code)
I searched online for javascript `&&` operator and it seems like `&&` doesn't work the way this code intended it to be.
But I think I might miss something here, can Javascript && handle this case?

Comment: there's no JSON at all in that code ... JSON is a String

Comment: `item.type && item.name` will always evaluate to either of the two, it will never return both.

Comment: May be using if/else blocks is the correct way to move forward with this problem statement.

Comment: The cleverest approach is probably to use the bitwise AND instead, for that case specifically. Replace `&&` with `&` and everything should work as expected, the bitwise AND will produce different results and will actually match the cases.

Comment: @briosheje I don't think that would result in expected result. `` 'name1' & 'value1'`` returns 0 and ``'name2' & 'value2'`` also returns 0

Comment: @MehrdadShokri you're right, indeed. Maybe there are cleverer approaches, let me see..

Comment: @MehrdadShokri I don't think there is any other way due to the default behavior of `switch case` that compares using strict comparison (`===`) hence you must provide a number or a string (or null or undefined) in order to be able to use a switch case as intended. Perhaps you can think about joining strings, but that would become slighly too complex to read and maintain. Otherwise, you may follow other approaches.

Comment: You could just concatenate the two strings: `type + name === 'Url' + 'Website'`.

Answer (score 1):

> But I think I might miss something here, can Javascript && handle this case?

No, javascript can't handle these.

Or, let's say the whole truth: it wouldn't in any case because it's **not** a language feature, it's just how `&&` works and meant to be used, since the `&&` operator in your scenario will always evaluate to the **right-hand** value if the **left-hand** value is truthy.

```js
console.log('a' && 'b'); // <-- left is truthy, hence 'b' is returned.
console.log(null && 'b'); // <-- left is falsy, hence null is returned.
console.log('b' && null); // <-- left is truthy, hence null (right) is returned.
console.log(null && null); // <-- left is falsy, hence null is returned.
```

So, in your scenario, your switch case really act by always looking at the `item.name` if `item.type` is truthy and will always look only for the right part of each `case`.

So, in case `item.name` is `TelegramPhoneNumber` it will **always** evaluate to the third case, unless `item.type` is falsy, as an example.

To summarize the logic of the current switch case, so, if `item.type` **is truthy**, the switch case **might** join either of the cases but the default one. Otherwise, if `item.type` is falsy, it will **always** join the `default` case.

Your switch case, so, could be rewritten as:

```
const wrapper = item => {
    switch (item.type && item.name) {
        case 'Website':
            return Text(values.Website)
        case 'Email':
            return Text(values.Email)
        case 'TelegramPhoneNumber':
            return Mobile(values.TelegramPhoneNumber)
        case 'Phone1':
            return Phone(values.Phone1)
        case 'Phone2':
            return Phone(values.Phone2)
        default:
            return Text(values[4])
    }
}
```

and would really act in the same way as before.

Finally, a `switch` statement would not work as intended if expressed in the provided way. It doesn't mean it won't work, it just won't work **as intended**, if it's working, it's because you either didn't encounter any limit case, either bacause most of the switch statement is just unneeded.

The reason behind that is that switch statements uses **strict comparison** when checking `case`, as mentioned in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

> A switch statement first evaluates its expression. It then looks for
>   the first case clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as
>   the result of the input expression **(using the strict comparison, ===)**
>   and transfers control to that clause, executing the associated
>   statements. (If multiple cases match the provided value, the first
>   case that matches is selected, even if the cases are not equal to each
>   other.)

So, the only feasible solution (the best I could think of) in your scenario to keep the switch as it currently is and make it work is a bit confusing:

```js
const wrapper = item => {
    switch ([item.type,item.name].join()) {
        case ['Url','Website'].join():
            return Text(values.Website)
        case ['Email','Email'].join():
            return Text(values.Email)
        case ['Mobile','TelegramPhoneNumber'].join():
            return Mobile(values.TelegramPhoneNumber)
        case ['Phone','Phone1'].join():
            return Phone(values.Phone1)
        case ['Phone','Phone2'].join():
            return Phone(values.Phone2)
        default:
            return Text(values[4])
    }
}

// Ignore these, it's just to don't make it crash.
const Text = i => i;
const Phone = i => i;
const Mobile = i => i;
const values = { Website: 'Website', Email: 'Email', TelegramPhoneNumber: 'TelegramPhoneNumber', Phone1: 'Phone1', Phone2: 'Phone2', 4: '4'};
// Endignore.

// Tests
const testFirst = { type: 'Url', name: 'Website', values };
const testThird = { type: 'Mobile', name: 'TelegramPhoneNumber', values };
const testDefault = {type: 'Hello', name: 'World', values };

console.log(wrapper(testFirst)); // Website expected
console.log(wrapper(testThird)); // TelegramPhoneNumber expected
console.log(wrapper(testDefault)); // 4 expected
```

The solution basically works by joining the two values, so the string comparison against these will work as expected.